# Using extern array in class method -> undefined reference

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain me why

```
#include <iostream>


namespace helper1 {
  void syncAPI();
};


void helper1::syncAPI() {
    extern int *arrayOfIntPointers[];
    std::cout << *arrayOfIntPointers[0] << std::endl;

}


int *arrayOfIntPointers[5];


int main()
{

  int *newInt = new int;
  
  *newInt = 1;
  helper1::syncAPI();
}
```

results in this error

> In function `helper1::syncAPI()': undefined reference to helper1::arrayOfIntPointers

instead of displaying '1'?

And why seems `arrayOfIntPointers` to be a member of `helper1` ( *helper1::* arrayOfIntPointers)?

EDIT: I want to access the global array from within the function `syncAPI()` because all necessary data will be stored there.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Please, provide some more info.

Comment: @89f3a1c Thanks for the suggestion. I want to access the global array from within the function `syncAPI()` because all necessary data are stored there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `extern int *arrayOfIntPointers[];` is still inside the namespace, even though it's an `extern` declaration. So it declares `helper1::arrayOfIntPointers`.

The definition `int *arrayOfIntPointers[5];` is outside a namespace, so it defines
`arrayOfIntPointers` in the "global" namespace - a different object.

To fix this, the `extern` declaration and the definition must match. Either define your `arrayOfIntPointers` inside your namespace or declare it outside the namespace. So you have two solutions:

1. Outside (preferred)

   ```
    extern int *arrayOfIntPointers[];
    void helper1::syncAPI()
    {
        ...
    }
   ```
2. Inside

   ```
    namespace helper1
    {
        int *arrayOfIntPointers[5];
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Because `arrayOfIntPointers` is not a member of namespace `helper1` and the `extern` declaration within the function is most likely not what you want.